# how can i split a full name to first name and last name in python?

Tags: python-3.x, string, split

I'm a novice in python programming and i'm trying to split full name to first name and last name, can someone assist me on this ? so my example file is:

Sarah Simpson

I expect the output like this : Sarah,Simpson

Comment: welcome to SO! Provide some code for your question: what you tried, etc See also  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **`split()`** function like so:

```
fullname=" Sarah Simpson"
fullname.split()
```

which will give you: `['Sarah', 'Simpson']`

**Building on that, you can do:**

```
first=fullname.split()[0]
last=fullname.split()[-1]
print(first + ',' + last)
```

which would give you **`Sarah,Simpson`** with no spaces

Comment: why [-1] on last ?

Comment: you could have done [1], but just in case there was a middle name, grabbing from the end

Answer (score 2):

This comes handly : nameparser 1.0.6 - https://pypi.org/project/nameparser/

```
>>> from nameparser import HumanName
>>> name = "Sarah Simpson"
>>> name = HumanName(name)
>>> name.last
'Simpson'
>>> name.first
'Sarah'
>>> name.last+', '+name.first
'Simpson, Sarah'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try the `.split()` function which returns a list of strings after splitting by a separator. In this case the separator is a space char.

first remove leading and trailing spaces using `.strip()` then split by the separator.

```
first_name, last_name=fullname.strip().split()
```

Answer (score 1):

Strings in Python are immutable. Create a new String to get the desired output.
You can use **split()** method of string class.

```
name = "Sarah Simpson"
name.split()
```

**split()** by default splits on whitespace, and takes separator as parameter. It returns a list

`["Sarah", "Simpson"]`

Just concatenate the strings. For more reference https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=split#str.split

```
Output = "Sarah", "Simpson"
```

Answer (score 0):

name = "Thomas Winter"
LastName = name.split()[1]
(note the parantheses on the function call split.)

split() creates a list where each element is from your original string, delimited by whitespace. You can now grab the second element using name.split()[1] or the last element using name.split()[-1]

Answer (score 0):

`split()` is obviously the function to go for-
which can take a parameter or 0 parameter

```
fullname="Sarah Simpson"
ls=fullname.split()
ls=fullname.split(" ") #this will split by specified space
```

*Extra Optional*

And if you want the split name to be shown as a string delimited by coma, then you can use `join()` or `replace`

```
print(",".join(ls))  #outputs Sarah,Simpson
print(st.replace(" ",","))
```

Answer (score 0):

Input: Sarah Simpson => suppose it is a string.
Then, to output: Sarah, Simpson. Do the following:

```
name_surname = "Sarah Simpson".split(" ")
to_output = name_surname[0] + ", " + name_surname[-1]
print(to_output)
```

The function split is executed on a string to split it by a specified argument passed to it. Then it outputs a list of all chars or words that were split. 
In your case: the string is "Sarah Simpson", so, when you execute split with the argument " " -empty space- the output will be: ["Sarah", "Simpson"].

Now, to combine the names or to access any of them, you can right the name of the list with a square brackets containing the index of the desired word to return. For example:  name_surname[0] will output "Sarah" since its index is 0 in the list.